# Disable only touch input in a Webview in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, dart

i've created a Webview widget and i want only to disable touch input, but not scrolling i tried with the classes "ignorePointer" and "AbsorbPointer", but that disable all input. the code sample below, load me a page (twitter-timeline), i want to be able to scrolldown the tweets.
Any Solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

```
IgnorePointer(
          child: WebView(
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            initialUrl: '',
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controller = webViewController;
              _loadHtmlFromAssets();
            },
          ),
        )
```

Comment: have you tried removing  `javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,`

Comment: i tried now, but it doesn't work, the page don't load

Comment: Try to set a url in initailUrl to make it work

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a little bit late, but I have the same issue and I solved it by restricting the navigation while the user taps a link:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebViewPlus(
      initialUrl: filePath,
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewPlusController webViewController) {
        _webViewController = webViewController;
      },
      navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
          if (request.url.startsWith('https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/widget_iframe') ||
             request.url.startsWith('about:blank') ||
             request.url.startsWith("http://localhost")) {
              print('allowing navigation to $request}');
              return NavigationDecision.navigate;
            }else {
              print('denying navigation to $request}');
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
      },
    );
  }
```